# Where does OWASP Dependency-Track actually scan to get data about a project?

Tags: owasp

I've scoured https://docs.dependencytrack.org/ for information on how to actually use Dependency-Track.

What does Dependency-Track actually scan to get the data about my software build?

When I run Dependency-Track -> Projects -> Create Project -> and give the project a name, it just takes me to the project overview and the vulns, components, and auditing graphs are all at zero.

Do I point it to Jenkins or to GitLab?  I don't see a place to put in the URL and creds for those locations in the project details.

Answer (score 1):

Have a closer look at https://docs.dependencytrack.org/usage/cicd/ .

You need to feed it with your project BOM. It will then compare components from BOM against known vulnerabilities.

How you do that depends. If you are using Jenkins then it will be a bit easier with a Jenkins plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/dependency-track/. If you are using GitLab CI then you need to use appropriate for your project SBOM generator from https://cyclonedx.org/tool-center/.